# use mobile emulation without using device toolbar in inspect tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Is there an easy way with js for example to trick the site into thinking it's being views on mobile like in the device toolbar in the inspect tools

I want to publish an old site I made with css properties that uses vh and vw to display the right size (it's a mobile based web app)

Comment: try to use media query to use desired CSS

Comment: the css uses the window size, so it won't solve it

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by using Iframe
loading the site into an Iframe with the width and height of a mobile and everything work well

I used a copy of the site as an iframe

```
<iframe style='width: 30%;height: 100vh;' src="./index copy.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```